# Responsive WordPress thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I can easily make images within a post responsive, but am have an issue getting custom post type thumbs to do the same b/c WP automatically inserts a width and height. I am looking for a way to at least override these default widths/heights on them. Anyone happen to have a solution for this?

Thanks in Advance!
- j

Comment: Should do what you're looking for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want in your CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The first declaration makes sure all images won't exceed the width of their containing element. The auto declaration for height ensures all images retain their proportions when scaled down even when they have size attributes in the `img` element. So in a way this overwrites the size attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use WP's `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to output the URL of the thumbnail and then proceed with building your own `<img/>` tag and responsive-ing it.

```
<img src="<?php $img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

If you want a specific size, insert this: `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large')`

Comment: Thanks for the response Indranil: how exactly would I implement the solution you are suggesting: would this be worked into the functions file, and then on the template file? And if so, how exaclty? All apologizes for being a bit of a noob.

Comment: No no, just put this in the template file where you want the image to show up.

Comment: Hmmm: still no luck Indranil. Could you possibly show me an example of it being applied to the format in which I am calling the thumbnails (and again, all apoligizes for the noob request):       <?php 
           if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
           }
          ?> Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="<?php $img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(
                get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),large); 
 echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"
                                    style="display:block; width:50%;"/>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.